# Eloquent model belongsTo relationship not working in L4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I have the following tables:

**users**

```
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username', 30);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**organisations**

```
    Schema::create('organisations', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique('name');
        $table->integer('owner_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and I have the following **Organisation** Eloquent model:

```
class Organisation extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'owner_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

On my controller, I load all `organisations` and pass it to the view like this:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('organisations.index')
        ->with('organisations', Organisation::all());
}
```

On my view, when I try to display the data like this:

```
@foreach($organisations as $organisation)
    <div>
        Name : {{  $organisation->name }}
        <br>
        Owner: {{ $organisation->owner()->email }}
    </div>
@endofreach
```

When I do this, I get a object is `null` exception.

I've also tried to use `hasOne` relationship and it didn't work either.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach($organisations as $organisation)
    <div>
        Name : {{  $organisation->name }}
        <br>
        Owner: {{ $organisation->owner->email }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Without the `()` on the owner. Like that you get a Model\User object and not a belongsTo Object. The BelongsTo object doesn't contain any of the user information but allows you to add more eloquent methods to filter the query.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I had not realised it was used as a property not as a method.